# Connection string in code vs app.config file

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to specify the connection string to an .accdb file in code on form startup instead of the app.config file.

I want the user to be able to specify where to install the accdb file and then make that connection to the user specified accdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible.

When you create your database connection, instead of referencing the application variable you can reference the value of a textbox (or any string, for that matter)

Just do something like this:
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source" & mystring & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Comment: so the user will have to set the value of string every time? :-)

Comment: and you can do this from within the app.config file?

Comment: @Shoban If that's what the app calls for, sure... The point is that there is absolutely a way to adjust your connection string from the form.

Comment: @Voyagr12 The app.config will store application configuration settings. If you are changing your connection string based on user input to a specific form then you won't be storing the value in the app.config file.

Comment: if i remove the connnection string from the app.config file Visual Studio throws all sorts of errors in relation to my dataset.

Comment: Don't remove it from the file, just tell your connection to use a different connection string.

Comment: I know how to create a new connection, but how would you change an existing connection?  ecspecially one that is already set up in the app.config file and the settings within Visual Studio. (which i believe are the same thing?)

Comment: You can close and re-open a connection with a new connection string.